# How to make a sub that stops when it finds a blank cell?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I was working on a database in Excell 2010 and found many duplicated names. I tried to make a VBA Script to solve this, but it just ends on a infinite loop. I wanted it to stop when it hits a blank cell. Heres the code I came up with

```
Sub excluirDuplicatas()

   Dim lngCont As Long
   Dim lngLinhas As Long
   Dim rngNom1 As Range
   Dim rngNom2 As Range

lngCont = 0
lngLinhas = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

While lngCont <= lngLinhas

Set rngNom1 = ActiveCell
Set rngNom2 = rngNom1.Offset(1, 0)

While rngNom1.Value = rngNom2.Value And rngNom2 <> lastRow


rngNom2.Select
rngNom2.EntireRow.Delete
Set rngNom2 = ActiveCell
Wend


Set rngNom1 = rngNom2
Set rngNom1 = ActiveCell



Set rngNom1 = rngNom2
rngNom1.Select

lngCont = lngCont + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

I don't know whats wrong, my guess is the part where I state

`rngNom2 <> Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`

Please be aware that I starded VBA Programing today(March 22th). If you could please post not only the answer but also a quick explanation I would appreciate.

PS: The data sheet has over 2000 lines long

Comment: A black cell or a blank cell?

Comment: Blank, i misspelled that. Sorry lol

Comment: Can you describe more specifically what it is you're trying to accomplish... Maybe we could show you nicer code to do the task... FOR EXAMPLE, In Excel, if you select your range and press `F5`, click `Special` and select `Blanks`, that will find all the blank cells in your range... If you then hit `Shift` + `Space Bar`, that will select the entire row... You can then delete that row (if that is what you were trying to do)... So, if you record a macro doing that, you can get what you want in 10 lines of code or less...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a For Loop so that you can avoid using `.Select` You might want to see [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

So for example your code will look something like this

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If Len(Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value)) = 0 Then Exit For

    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks, but I acctualy used the lastRow argument and it worked out just fine. But i'll keep in mind the use of the "For" routine for my next codes!

Comment: @Pedro: If you are sure that there is no blank cell before the last row then you may see this link as well to find the last row... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

I think this command will help you.  Replace `Range("a1")` with whatever range you want to test.

`IsEmpty(Range("a1"))`

ie, `do while isempty(range("a1"))`... or `do while not isempty(range("a1"))`

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not 100% sure what you're doing, but this would be a start.

Start by declaring a range variable `rng` taht contains all the cells you want to examine. The way I have set this `rng` variable **automatically stops at the first blank cell in the column**.

We will use the counter `r` to iterate over these cells, from last to first (this is necessary when deleting).

We will use a variable `cl` as a single cell range, during this iteration.

```
Sub excluirDuplicatas()

Dim rng as Range
Dim r as Integer 'row counter.
Dim cl As Range


lngCont = 0
lngLinhas = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

set rng = Range(ActiveCell.Address, Range(ActiveCell.Address).End(xlDown)) 

For r = rng.Rows.Count to 1 Step - 1 'Step backwards when deleting, otherwise you have infinite loop

    'This tests to see if the cell value is the same as the value below it.
     ' and deletes it if it is the same value.
    If cl.Value = cl.Offset(1,0).Value Then
        cl.EntireRow.Delete

    End If
Next
```

End Sub